# IOS Facebook Authentication Using node.js passport-facebook-token

Tags: ios, node.js, api, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate to a node.js api using [passport-facebook-token](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token) from an IOS app.

I have username and password auth set-up and working fine through passport and the passport-facebook-token set-up as per the example.

```
passport.use(new FacebookTokenStrategy({
clientID: config.facebook.clientID,
clientSecret: config.facebook.clientSecret
},
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
User.findOrCreate({ facebookId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
return done(err, user);
});
```

I just cant figure out the HTTP request syntax needed to send the access token across to the  API.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK managed to work out the answer from the strategy file from passport-facebook-token

It requires:

http://URL?access_token=[access token]

From IOS i simply tested this with:

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
NSLog(@"This is token: %@", fbAccessToken);        
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myapi.url.com/auth/facebook?access_token=%@",fbAccessToken]];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
NSURLResponse *res;
NSError *err;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&res error:&err];
if (!err) {
NSLog(@"The user is logged in on the server side too");
} else {
NSLog(@"Error occurred. %@", err);
}
});
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: How does your nodejs code look like? I'm trying similar solution but it says "Error: no strategy registered under name: facebook". How are you creating your routes?

Comment: I just looked in the strategy file

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this with a header. Curl for that

```
curl localhost:3000/endpoint -H "Authorization: Bearer <facebook token>"
```